# Val() in IIF() not working

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a formula in an access query with Val() in the true part of IIF().  Val() is not recognized.  I have tried it as false but get the same result.

RoomType: IIf(IsNumeric([tblRoomTypes]![RoomType])=True,Val([tblRoomTypes]![RoomType]),[tblRoomTypes]![RoomType])

Comment: I know a lot of access, but I'm not familiar with that syntax. In which context is the `:` syntax you have there valid? Is it possible you need to prefix your formula with a `=`? Also, not that the `=True` part should be unnecessary.

Comment: K I think I got it, you're entering it into the Field box on the query editor. Setting up a test of your example, it works for me using the same naming you have, even copying your statement directly into the window. I would check that you've entered it correctly in your window. If you're getting an error that `Val` is unknown, it's possible you have a reference problem, or that your VBA code is in some kind of error state, in which case I would try restarting access. To check for missing references, you have to go to the VB editor, and then choose Tools -> References.

Comment: Also make sure to run Debug->Compile in the VBA Editor and fix all errors it might show.

Comment: Your expression makes no sense as the possible result from _Val_ would be casted back to text making the use of Val moot. So what example values do you have, and what output do you request?

Comment: Why would Val() be cast back to text?  Does IIf() automatically force everything to the column format?  I can't merely use Val() since the field can have alpha characters.  Unfortunately in cases where they are all numeric they do not sort correctly.